# What is the theorem that approximate a "success" 1 out N probability tried N times, 2N times, etc, for not succeeding at least once?

Tags: probability, euler-mascheroni-constant

That is, if the probability of success is 1/450, so failing means 449/450, then if we try it 450 times, then the chance of failing (not succeeding even one time) is:

$$ (449/450) ^ {450} = 0.367470307338961$$

and it can be approximated by

$$ e^{-1} = 0.367879441171442 $$

and if we try 900 times, it is:

$$ (449/450) ^ {900} = 0.13503442677579 $$

and since $ 900 $ is $ 450 \times 2 $, so we approximate using:

$$ e^{-2} = 0.135335283236613 $$

And it doesn't have to be $ 450 $. It can be $ 200, 700, 800, $ or $ 1200 $.

Is there a name of this theorem? And perhaps its origin of how it got found out?

Comment: $e^x=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^n$

Comment: Are you aware that good answers can be accepted? I´m asking because I´ve seen your other 9 questions.

Comment: @callculus on StackOverflow sometimes we just left the answers "become the accepted one" by getting the most vote. Some answers I really can accept it. Some I can't because I don't know enough about the answer or whether yet another better answer exists or not

Comment: I fully understand your arguments. But you haven´t accepted any answer. That  I cannot comprehend.

Comment: @parsiad the 3 questions you quoted, I can't yet understand fully the answers, so it'd be a disservice to other readers if I actually make it an "accepted answer". I also hope to finally see an answer that is so clear and understandable to appear later, if it is to get marked as an accepted answer. And isn't the accepted answer just to get more points in the system? If a user is not ready to accept an answer, is he or she required to? If a user doesn't accept an answer and let the votes do the talking, isn't that acceptable behavior?

Comment: @parsiad Ultimately, is there a rule that says a user *must* accept an answer, especially even when he or she feels not ready to do so

Comment: @parsiad you know, I feel people on Internet come up to say other people are wrong, or bad, and it seems like that "makes their day". One time, I skied down and a person all of a sudden start moving all the way to the left side of the slope without watching the ongoing traffic. It is like a car pulling out of a curb without looking from behind. Yet, he commented "YOU SHOULD LOOK AT PEOPLE DOWNHILL. THAT'S THE ETIQUETTE." People just see other people wrong or improper and he himself is "right". You come up here, and start saying other people bad or fart, that's really unnice behavior

Comment: I am happy to concede that I am not nice. I hope you still consider adopting Math.SE conventions in the future. All the best.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I could find the definition of $e$, but what about the definition of $e^x$ -- does it have a name or can you quote some source or reference?

Comment: see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function); I just noticed in my comment above I made a typo.:  it should have been $\lim\limits_{\color{red}n\to\infty}$

Answer (score 1):

This is already expressed in J. W. Tanner's comment.

By Taylor's theorem, $e^x = 1 + x + O(x^2)$.
Therefore, for a fixed integer $k$,
$$
\lim_n \left(1 - k/n \right)^n
= \lim_n \left(
  e^{-k/n} + O((k/n)^2)
\right)^{n}
= e^{-k} + \lim_n \sum_{j = 1}^n
  O((k/n)^{2j}) e^{-(n-j)k/n}
= e^{-k}.
$$
Moreover, since $1 - k/n = (n - k)/n$, we can interpret $(1 - k/n)^n$ as the probability of not succeeding even once in an experiment with $n$ trials and success probability $k/n$.

The above suggests that when $n$ is large,
$$\left(1 - k/n\right)^n \approx e^{-k}.$$

In your example, $k=1$, but you can take $k=2$ or $k=3$ (etc.) to arrive at $e^{-2}$ or $e^{-3}$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1-1/n)^n=e^{-1}$ follows directly from a definition of $e^x$

Comment: Depends on how you define $e$. Is $e$ the limit of $(1+1/n)^n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Or is $e$ the unique number which makes $f^\prime \equiv f$ where $f(x) = e^x$? Etc.

Comment: That's why I said **a** definition; and when you wrote $\lim\limits_n,$ did you mean $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$?

Comment: Yep, I generally abbreviate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ to $\lim_n$.

Comment: @parsiad are you saying when $ n \rightarrow \infty $? and that 450 or 900 or 1200 is quite large enough? Well, then what about the case with $ e ^ {-2} $ and $ e ^ {-3} $ etc?

Comment: @太極者無極而生: That's right; see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it is [Bernoulli Trails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Bernoulli_trials). If the probability of succeeding per trial is $1/n$, then not succeeding once after $n$ trails is $e^{-1}$. So using this fact, if you try it $2n$ times and not succeeding, then it is

$$ e^{-1} \times e^{-1} = \frac 1 e \times \frac 1 e = \frac 1 {e^2} = e^{-2} $$

and you can use similar calculations if it is $3n$, $4n$ times, and so forth.

---

If you are interested in how it can be derived:

First, [the original definition of Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) $e$ is:

$$ e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n $$

by Jacob Bernoulli in 1683 (although he didn't use the letter $e$). Euler started to use the letter $e$ for the constant in 1727 or 1728.

And it can be derived, or [some reference even states that this is the definition of $e^x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Characterizations):

$$ e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac x n\right)^n $$

Now we can let $x = -1$ and it becomes
$$\begin{align} e^{-1} & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac {-1} n\right)^n  \\
& = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac {1} n\right)^n \\
\end{align}$$

So if we use a somewhat large number $n$, such as $450$:

$$\begin{align}
e^{-1} & \approx \left(1-\frac {1} {450}\right)^{450} \\
& = \left(\frac {450} {450} -\frac {1} {450}\right)^{450} \\
& = \left(\frac {450 - 1} {450}\right)^{450}\\
& = \left(\frac {449} {450}\right)^{450}\\
\end{align}$$

Now note the above is exactly: the probably of not succeeding even once out of 450 trials, when the probability of succeeding in one try is $\frac 1 {450}$.

What about trying 900 times?  Then since

$$ \left(\frac {449} {450}\right)^{450} \approx  e^{-1} $$

If we square both sides:

$$\begin{align}
\left( \left(\frac {449} {450}\right)^{450}\right)^2 & \approx \left(e^{-1}\right)^2\\ 
\left(\frac {449} {450}\right)^{900} & \approx e^{-2}\\
& = \frac 1 {e^2}\\
\end{align}$$

and similar calculations can be done for $450 \times 3 = 1350$ tries: $$ e^{-3} \text{ or } \frac 1 {e^3} $$
 or $450 \times 4 = 1800 $ tries: $$ e^{-4} \text { or } \frac 1 {e^4}$$

In fact, one of the applications of Euler's number, besides the original study of Compound Interest at the time done by Bernoulli, is [Bernoulli Trails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Bernoulli_trials) related to probability. If the probability of succeeding per trial is $1/n$, then not succeeding once after $n$ trails is $e^{-1}$. So using this fact, if you try it $2n$ times and not succeeding, then it is

$$ e^{-1} \times e^{-1} = \frac 1 e \times \frac 1 e = \frac 1 {e^2} = e^{-2} $$